# PHP - Updating / Editing Data / Records In The Database Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

So I'm currently playing around with PHP and making a "blog" system. I want to user to be able to edit the topic name of their own posts. Currently when you edit a topic name, all of the other topic names changes no matter which user made the post.

- Only edit the current topic name.
- Only the editor who made the post can edit that post.

topic.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
require('connect.php');
if (@$_SESSION["username"]) {

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Home page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<center>

<?php 
    if (@$_GET['id']) {
        $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_id='".$_GET['id']."'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($check) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check)) {
                $check_u = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$row['topic_creator']."'");
                while ($row_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_u)) {
                    $user_id = $row_u['id'];
                }

                echo "<h1>".$row['topic_name']."</h1>";
                echo "<h5>By <a href='profile.php?id=$user_id'>".$row['topic_creator']."</a><br />Date: ".$row['date']."</h5>";
                echo "<br />".$row['topic_content'];
                echo "<br /><br /><img src='img/".$row['image']."' width='300' />";
                echo "<br /><br /><a href='edit.php?edit=".$row['topic_id']."'>Edit</a>";
            }

        }else {
            echo "Topic not found.";
        }
    }


?>

</center>

 </body>
</html>

 <?php 

}else {
    echo "You must be logged in.";
}

?>
```

edit.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
require('connect.php');
if (@$_SESSION["username"]) {

 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Home page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>

<center>

<?php 

if( isset($_GET['edit']) )
    {
        $id = $_GET['edit'];
        $res= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topics");
        $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    }

    if( isset($_POST['newTn']) )
    {
        $newTn = $_POST['newTn'];
        // $id       = $_POST['id'];
        $sql     = "UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$newTn'";
        $res     = mysql_query($sql) 
                                    or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
    }

?>

<form action="edit.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type="text" name="newTn" value=<?php echo $row['topic_name']; ?>><br />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="">
<input type="submit" value=" Update "/>
</form>

</center>

</body>
</html>

<?php


if (@$_GET['action'] == "logout")   {
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
}

}else {
    echo "You must be logged in.";
}

  ?>
```

Thanks beforehand! 
//E

Comment: Use a WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement (`WHERE topic_id =?`); and use placeholders (`?`), don't interpolate values into SQL-statements. Also, don't use the `msql_` family of functions, but `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: This code shouldn't be used in a live environment, I hope you realize that and there are quite a few gaping sql injection holes. If used in a live environment, you stand at getting your database hacked and possibly losing all your information, and/or your users' vital information being stolen.

Comment: if you're playing around with php look into using a framework for php such as https://www.codeigniter.com/ or https://laravel.com/ . Both come with build in query builders and security features to help you out.

Comment: You're also using a deprecated api that is no longer supported in PHP 7.0. If and when your server gets upgraded to that version of PHP, you will need to do a total rewrite. Stay ahead of the game and stop what you're doing and rewrite it now using a prepared statement.

Comment: This question is getting too many duplicated answers, that's really unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql     = "UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$newTn' where topic_id = '".$_GET['edit]."'";
```

You have passed the topic id from Grid and you need to attach that in query

Answer (score 3):

In edit.php

You need to specify the post id to be edited in the query.

```
if( isset($_POST['newTn']) )
    {
        $newTn = $_POST['newTn'];
        $id       = $_POST['id'];
        //notice here the $id is added as where clause to filter the edit on one row only
        $sql     = "UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$newTn' WHERE post_id = '$id'";
        $res     = mysql_query($sql) 
                                    or die("Could not update".mysql_error());
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=index.php'>";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specifies the id of the topic in the query UPDATE :

```
 $sql     = "UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$newTn' where id=$session[yourtopicID]" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `edit.php` change `UPDATE topics SET topic_name='$newTn'` query to below

```
UPDATE topics SET topic_name = '$newTn' where `yourTopicId` = '$_GET[edit]'
```